# Javascript Nested For Loop not updating array when returning it

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, nested

```
let posts = [];
for(var i = user.posts.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
  posts.push(user.posts[i]);
}
for(var i = 0; i < user.friends.length; i++){
 let query = {username:user.friends[i]};
 User.findOne(query, function(err, theuser){
  if(err) throw err;

  if(theuser){
    if(theuser.posts.length > 0){
      for(var j = theuser.posts.length - 1; j >= 0; j--){
        posts.push(theuser.posts[j]);
      }
    }
  }
});
} 
return posts;
```

So my problem is that when I call this function, posts is not returning correctly. When i run this i want to return an array of posts and the first for loop works good but when i want to push an element to the array from the nest for loop where the var = j, it is not updating the posts array. I think it might have something to do with async function but im not sure on how to implement it in my case.

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong with your code. It may help to see how you're testing the code and what values you're seeing returned vs what you're expecting.

Comment: Why is this tagged `async`/`await`? Do plan using promises?

Comment: `.findOne()` is asynchronous. `return posts` is executed before `posts.push(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

You [cannot *return* from asynchronous functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call); at least not like you're doing.

```
let posts = []
// ...
for(var i = 0; i < user.friends.length; i++){
  // ...
  User.findOne(query, function(err, theuser){
    // nothing here happens before `return posts` is called below
  })
} 
return posts;
```

This should help put you back on the right path -

```
// reverse copy of user posts
const posts =
  [ ...user.posts ].reverse()

// "promisified" findOne
const findOne = query =>
  User.findOne
    ( query
    , (err, res) =>
        err
          ? Promise.reject(err)
          : Promise.resolve(res)
    )

Promise
  .all(user.friends.map(username => findOne({ username }))
  .map(friend => friend.posts.reverse())
  .then(friendPosts => posts.concat(friendPosts)
  .then
     ( allPosts =>
         // do something with all posts here
     )
```

The alternative is `async`/`await`. Here we also use [`util.promisify`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) instead of rewriting `findOne` by hand -

```
const { promisify } =
  require('util')

const findOne =
  promisify(User.findOne)

// below, `async` functions always return a promise
const allPostsAndFriendsPosts = async (user) =>
{ // write normal synchronous code here
  let res =
    [ ...user.posts ].reverse()

  // inside async functions, we can `await` a promise
  const friends =
    await Promise.all(user.friends.map(username => findOne({ username }))

  // then use the promised value synchronously
  for (const f of friends)
    res = res.concat(f.posts.reverse())

  return res // <-- returns a promise
}

allPostsAndFriendsPosts(user)
  .then
    ( allPosts =>
        // do something with all posts
    )
```

---

`async` and `await` are the tandem duo of this era. I just want to offer an appreciation of their combined capability. Say you have a database -

```
const DB = 
  { '/0': { a: 'a', _link: '/1' }
  , '/1': { b: 'b', _link: '/2' }
  , '/2': { c: 'c', d: 'd', _link: '/3' }
  , '/3': { e: 'e' }

  , '/4': { f: 'f', _link: '/5' }
  , '/5': { g: 'g' }

  // ...
  }
```

Where each node has a path like `/0`, `/1`, etc, and nodes can link to other nodes using the `_link` property. Chains of link->link->link are not limited in length. Given a starting node, the goal is to produce the entire sequence of nodes –

```
recursiveGet ('/0') .then (console.log, console.error)
// [ { a: 'a' }, { b: 'b' }, { c: 'c', d: 'd' }, { e: 'e' } ]

recursiveGet ('/4') .then (console.log, console.error)
// [ { f: 'f' }, { g: 'g' } ]

recursiveGet ('/99') .then (console.log, console.error)
// Error: path not found: /99
```

We need some way to define a *loop*, some way to *initialize* it, some way to do the *next* loop, and finally some way to say when the loop is *done*. Oh and everything has to be async.

It's a tall order, but `async` and `await` are up to the task. When writing generic functions, we keep things as generic as possible to maximize reusability -

```
const asyncUnfold = async (loop, init) =>

  // call the user's loop with
  loop

      // the "next" function
      // accepts two arguments
      // 1. the item to add to the result
      // 2. the next accumulator
    ( async (x, acc) =>
        // the item is prepended to the recursive result
        [ x, ...await asyncUnfold (f, acc) ]

      // the "done" function
      // accepts one argument
      // 1. then final item of the result
    , async (x) => [ x ]

      // initial accumulator
    , init
    )
```

Given a `get` function that does *not* do a recursive query -

```
const get = async (url = '') =>
  fetch (url) .then (res => res .json ())
```

We can now write `recursiveGet` using `asyncUnfold` -

```
const recursiveGet = async (initUrl) =>

  // use our new magic wand
  asyncUnfold

      // our loop
      // receives 3 arguments
      // 1. the "next" function
      // 2. the "done" function
      // 3. the accumulator
    ( async (next, done, { _link, ...res }) =>

        // if we have a _link ...
        _link

          // add res to the output
          // the next step is get(_link)
          ? next (res, await get (_link))

          // otherwise there is no _link
          // call done with the last result
          : done (res)

    // initial accumulator
    , await get (initUrl)
    )
```

And all without having to touch `Promise`, `reject`, `resolve`, or `then`. I hope this gives you a glimpse of the capable expressions that can be made using `async` and `await`. Verify the results in your browser below -

```js
const asyncUnfold = async (f, init) =>
  f ( async (x, acc) => [ x, ...await asyncUnfold (f, acc) ]
    , async (x) => [ x ]
    , init
    )
    
const get = async (url = '') =>
  fetch (url) .then (res => res .json ())
  
const recursiveGet = async (initUrl) =>
  asyncUnfold
    ( async (next, done, { _link, ...res }) =>
        _link
          ? next (res, await get (_link))
          : done (res)
    , await get (initUrl)
    )
 
const DB = 
  { '/0': { a: 'a', _link: '/1' }
  , '/1': { b: 'b', _link: '/2' }
  , '/2': { c: 'c', d: 'd', _link: '/3' }
  , '/3': { e: 'e' }
  , '/4': { f: 'f', _link: '/5' }
  , '/5': { g: 'g' }
  }

// fake fetch for demo
const fetch = (url = '') =>
  DB[url] === undefined
    ? Promise .reject (Error(`path not found: ${url}`)) .then (delay)
    : Promise .resolve ({ json: () => DB[url] }) .then (delay)

// fake delay for demo
const delay = (x, ms = 250) =>
  new Promise (r => setTimeout (r, ms, x))
  
recursiveGet ('/0') .then (console.log, console.error)
// [ { a: 'a' }, { b: 'b' }, { c: 'c', d: 'd' }, { e: 'e' } ]
```